# How to animate another element on hover of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, css-transitions

I have a HTML 5 range element. What I need to do is when the user hover over the range, the height and width of the thumb should increase to 12 pixels.

CSS

```
.myrange::-webkit-slider-thumb{
     position:relative;
     top:-5px;
     appearance:none;
     -webkit-appearance:none;
     -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 4s;
     transition: width 2s, height 4s;
     border-radius:50px;
     background-color:rgb(9,90,0);
     border:0;
     cursor:pointer;
     visibility:hidden;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var skb_rhdaseek = $("<style>", {"type": "text/css"}).appendTo("head");
$('.myrange').hover(function(){
    skb_rhdaseek.text('.myrange::-webkit-slider-thumb{height:12px; width:12px;}');
});
```

Comment: `$(hoverelem).hover(function(){  $(anotherleelem).animate(function(){});  });`

Comment: Your code has lots of  issues,  Also by the looks of it you are trying to change the styles of the same element.

Comment: @RajshekarReddy That's why I couldn't do it myself, My code doesn't quite matter, If you have a better way of animating `range thumb` on hover of `range itselft` I would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add -webkit-appearance: none to your whole range element as well so that its thumb would get styled. And finally you don't need jquery to do that.

```css
.myrange {
 -webkit-appearance: none; 
 height:10px;
 width:200px;
 background-color:#e3f2fd;
}

.myrange::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: #33aaff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  transition: height .2s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=range]:hover::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" class="myrange" value="50">
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out!

```js
$('input').mouseenter(function() {
  $('input').toggleClass('over');
});
$('input').mouseleave(function() {
  $('input').toggleClass('over');
})
```

```css
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -14px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d; 
}

/* All the same stuff for Firefox */
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* All the same stuff for IE */
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range].over::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
}

/* All the same stuff for Firefox */
input[type=range].over::-moz-range-thumb {
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
}

/* All the same stuff for IE */
input[type=range].over::-ms-thumb {
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #3071a9;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #3071a9;
}
input[type=range].over::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 6px;
}
input[type=range].over::-moz-range-track {
  height: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='range'>
```

Comment: Sry, My question is how to animate the range thumb not the range tracker And animatedly not to change the height. similar to youtube videos thumb! And thanks for your reply!